# Finding the flow of water in a connected network

Tags: algorithm, openlayers-3

I have a set of water meters for water consumers drawn up as geojson and visualized with ol3. For each consumer house i have their usage of water for the given year, and also the water pipe system is given as linestrings, with metadata for the diameter of each pipe section.

What is the minimum required information I need to be able to visualize/calculate the amount of water that passed each pipe in total of the year when the pipes have inner loops/circles.

is there a library that makes it easy to do the calculations in javascript.

Naive approach, start from each house and move to the first pipe junction and add the used mater measurement for the house as water out of the junction and continue until the water plant is reached. This works if there was no loops within the pipe system.

Comment: Add an example that shows where the problem is.

Comment: Could you give an example explaining how the data will look like. For example can it be that the water connection that reaches the first house in its line will be able to consume all the water and the next houses will not get any water at all?

Comment: Would it be reasonable to assume that water just repeatedly flows through the loops at an unknown speed until it is consumed by a house? In that case you'd have no way to calculate the volume that flowed through particular cycles. Could you ignore cycles or make a simplifying assumption that water in cycles is still until drawn out by a house?

Comment: Is your question regarding avoiding loops and visiting all the house endpoints efficienctly? If that's the case, then a dfs should work with houses and junctions as nodes of graph.

Comment: The network looks like this: https://free.iiifhosting.com/iiif/838e350432ae63ec4910ec40da2354959ea2fa7d4db80c22b375b1992c21f16e/ blue lines are water pipes and red circles are connections to hourses. The diameter of the edges are on the diagram also, and for each house i know the yearly usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds more like a physics or civil engineering problem than a programming one.

But as best I can tell, you would need time series data for sources and sinks.

Consider this simple network:

[image: simple network]

Say, A is a source and B and D are sinks/outlets.
If the flow out of B is given, the flow in |CB| would be dependent on the flow out of D.

So e.g. if B and D were *always* open at the same time, the total volume that has passed |CB| might be close to 0. Conversely, if B and D were *never* open at the same time the number might be equal to the volume that flowed through |AB|.

If you can obtain time series data, so you have concurrent values of flow through D and B, I would think there would exist a standard way of determining the flow through |CB|.

Wikipedia's [Pipe Network Analysis article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipe_network_analysis) mentions one such method: The [Hardy Cross method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy_Cross_method), which:

"*assumes that the flow going in and out of the system is known and that the pipe length, diameter, roughness and other key characteristics are also known or can be assumed*".

If time series data are not an option, I would pretend it was always average (which might not be so bad given a large network, like in your image) and then do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm to find the maximum flow in a network.  To use this algorithm, you need to represent your network as a graph with nodes that represent your houses and edges to represent your pipes.

Answer (score 0):

You can first simplify the network by consolidating demands on "dead-ends". Next you'll need pressure data at the 3 feeds into this network, which I see as the top feed from the 90 (mm?), centre feed at the 63 and bottom feed near to the 50. These 3 clusters are linked by a 63mm running down, which have the consolidated demand and the pressure readings at the feed would be sufficient to give the flowrate across the inner clusters.